# How to add dynamic html page using c# or Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have created dynamic control in one panel using Jquery with movable option(draggable) in ASP.net with c#, now the requirement is like i have to save that panel as separate html page by clicking create button. and i have to show to user , if any modification has done in that panel(adding controls) then that has to save.

```
function AddLabel() { 
    var idl = document.getElementById('Autolbl').value; 
    var Panel = $('#cntpnl'); 
    Panel.append("<br /><label id=Llb" + idl 
       + " title='Click Properties Tab to Change the Text' 
         onmouseup='MLup(this.id)'             
         onmousedown='MLdown(this.id)'> Label </label>"); 

    var draglbl = "Llb" + idl; 

    $(function () { 
        $("#"+draglbl).draggable({ cancel: null }); 
    }); 

    idl++; 

    document.getElementById('Autolbl').value = idl; 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some code?

Comment: function AddLabel() { 
    var idl = document.getElementById('Autolbl').value;
    var Panel = $('#cntpnl');
    Panel.append("<br /><label id=Llb" + idl + " title='Click Properties Tab to Change the Text' onmouseup='MLup(this.id)' onmousedown='MLdown(this.id)'> Label </label>");
    var draglbl = "Llb" + idl;
    $(function () {
        $("#"+draglbl).draggable({ cancel: null });
    });
    idl++;
    document.getElementById('Autolbl').value = idl;
    return false;
}

Comment: the above is how i have added lable dynamically

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? Include everything in the question itself.

Comment: i have mailed to you, complete application. please check you mail tariqulazam@gmail.com

Comment: the Subject will be "Need Help on Dynamic Html page creation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button and hidden field like this in your page

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create HTML Page"         onclick="btnCreate_Click" />

<input type="hidden" id="txtHTML" runat="server"/>
```

Add the following javascript code at the bottom of the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               $("#<%=btnCreate.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                   $("#<%=txtHTML.ClientID %>").val($("#cntpnl").html());
                   return true;
               });
           });
```

Server side code for Create HTML page button

```
var html = txtHTML.Value.ToString();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\Test.htm", html);
```

Please remember to set ValidateRequest="false" in the page directive otherwise the postback will through an exception.

I don't like the approach at all but I think you have already developed your thing this way.